# Creating a custom time picker

Tags: android, timepicker

I need to create a custom time picker that includes seconds. Is there a generic control in Android that can be used for each of the input controls (hours, minutes and seconds)? It would look and function like the TimePicker with the +/- buttons.

Answer (score 0):

There's an [opensource Time picker with second](https://github.com/IvanKovac/TimePickerWithSeconds).

Otherwise you should create your own datepicker, by using the Time-class and three [NumberPickers](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/NumberPicker.html).

Comment: Those only allow you to pick time with hours and minutes. You cannot pick seconds with those, nor are those generic Picker controls that you can reuse for custom controls.